# Can't login with another domain credentials even when a trust exists

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

I have a domain named A;  it has 2 AD servers and some web servers. And this is configured to have a one way trust with a domain named B. In short, A trusts B, but B doesn't A.

Also, the users of domain B can log in to any of the servers in A domain with their B account. But now, while trying to log in with their B account, they're getting the error "No logon servers available."

I believe to have some kind of trust relationship error, but I'm a beginner. Can anyone help me on this?  How we can check for an error in trust relationships?

All servers involved are 2008R2.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe to have some kind of trust relationship error

Reading the error message (cough) tells you that is not the case.

> "No logon servers available" error is throwing out

Check DNS entries on both sides. This is typiical when no DC can be found / reached. Check the relevant DC error logs whether they work flawless.

This is - as the error says - not a TRUST issue. Trust is configured correctly. This is an issue of the DC discovery not workig and that can have a ton of reasons.

Basically the machine at A tries to find a server to aithenticate the user B and there is none it can find.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will check from my side. But before that may I ask u one thing..

I have an app pool in IIS configured to start with a user of A domain. Whenever the site is browsed, this app pool gets stopped. We havent done any changes in AD so far. Is this issue connected with above? Any idea?

Comment: Advice? Hire a professional. Do not think we can solve issues like that in a Q&A format because you don't even know where to look so it is painfull. Get some books and learn AD - front to end. WIthout this this just is going to be tendious to find as we cna not check every possible issue you did.

Answer (score 1):

> **Can anyone help me on this how we can check for any error in trust
>   relationship?**

You can go through the steps to verify the trust is working.

[Verify A Trust](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753821.aspx)

[image]

You can also look at running DCDIAG commands on domain controllers in both domains, as well as checking SYSTEM event logs on the domain controllers in both domains.  These may help narrow down the issue if the trust validation succeeds just fine.

As far as your "IIS app pool" follow up question to TomTom, I would suggest asking that as a separate question along with IIS errors and logs.